# Android - What replaces the NineOldAndroids animation library?

Tags: android, migration, android-animation, android-support-library, nineoldandroids

The NineOldAndroids animation library by Jake Wharton has been deprecated since July 2014.  I'd like to replace it in my app since we're targeting API 16+ now.

I've looked all over but can't find a guide to migrating from NineOldAndroids to the Support Library.  I've seen general comments about using `ViewCompat` and `ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat`, but not much else.  For example, I'm not sure how to replace `com.nineoldandroids.animation.Keyframe.FloatKeyframe`.

I understand that I can dig through the NineOldAndroids source to see which core Android animation classes it uses, but that wouldn't help me transition to the Support Library for animation.  Also, I'm guessing that others have already gone through this migration and might be willing to share their knowledge and notes.

Does anyone know which specific Support Library classes and modules replace the ones in NineOldAndroids?  Is there a known set of migration steps to take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think now you have "Android-Physics-based" Animation library as announced by Goolge in I/O 2017 which is a good replacement for NineOldsAndroid Library.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:support-dynamic-animation:26.0.0-beta1"
}
```